# My Macro does not pick up the value "#N/A" to clear contents

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a range of data from Column A to J (rows can vary). What I need my macro to do is to pick up any where the cell value in Row a is either IGNORE or #N/A and clear the contents of the entire row. whereafter I have VBA delete all blank rows. The problem I am experiencing is that VBA does not want to pick up the "#N/A" value and clear the contents - if I leave this out, it does exactly what I want with only IGNORE.

Please can someone assist - I think it may have something to do with N/A not being picked up as text?.

Thank you.

```
Dim end_range As Double
Dim n As Double

'Set the range in which to search for Ignore

Sheets("Submit").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
end_range = ActiveCell.Row

'Store the values of in a range
ReDim storeval(end_range)

For n = 1 To end_range
    storeval(n) = Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, 1)).Value
    Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 2)).Value = storeval(n)
Next n

'Delete the entirerow if the value contains ignore or N/A
For n = 1 To end_range
    If storeval(n) = "IGNORE" Or storeval(n) = "#N/A" Then
    Range("A" & n).EntireRow.ClearContents
    End If
Next n

Sheets("Submit").Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `=NA()` in your cells, then the `#N/A` that you see is just a text representation of an error object.
So instead of using the `storeval(n) = "#N/A"`, you need to test if :

- it is an error, using `IsError`
- it is the NA error using `CVErr(xlErrNA)`

Here is a little function that will give you true is the cell is NA and false if it is not NA :

```
Function IsNa(value)
    If Not IsError(value) Then
        IsNa = False
    ElseIf value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        IsNa = True
    Else
        IsNa = False
    End If
End Function
```

Then just call it by `IsNa(storeval(n))`

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but where in my code do I call it?

Comment: `If storeval(n) = "IGNORE" Or IsNa(storeval(n)) Then`

Answer (score 2):

To spot `"#N/A"` you need to look for cell's value `CVErr(xlErrNA)`

You might also want to switch your `If` and `Or` with `Select Case`

```
For n = 1 To end_range
    Select Case storeval(n)
        Case "IGNORE", CVErr(xlErrNA)
            Range("A" & n).EntireRow.ClearContents
    End Select
Next n
```

Comment: I deleted my post, and I think we both went too quickly, runtime error if the cell is erroneous.

Comment: Thanks for this, however when I insert the case function where the if would be it gives me the error type mismatch. Also, just a quick question. the #N/A that I have in my cells are because of previous formula errors , but in the sheet I am looking at they are pasted as value (cell format general). Would the CvErr(xlErrNA) still pick them up?